# When I send an email using emailoperator in airflow, how can I get the task id that triggered it?

Tags: email, airflow, task

[the graph of dag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOIJW.png)

As shown in the image above, there are many upstream tasks associated with `oneTaskFailed`.

I set that as long as one task fails, an email alert will be triggered.

But when I send an email, how do I determine the task ID that triggered the alert and send a log link of the task at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the onTaskFailed you can get the dag_run from the context.

And then you can find the TaskInstances that run in the current dag and find the one with the error state.

```
def on_failed_task(**context):
    dagrun: DAG = context["dag_run"]
    failed_ti = [ti for ti in dagrun.get_task_instances() if ti.state == State.FAILED]
    print(failed_ti)
```

Comment: It's great, I used it in the EmailOperator's `html_content`, thanks a lot.